# xcode swift 3D arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to build a 3D array. Here is a code that i modified from a 2D array. The 3D array does not print my arrays out, from the values that i defined it to be. There is something wrong with my getter and setter inside my subscripts. Can someone advise me?

```
import UIKit


class Array3D {
    var zs:Int, ys:Int, xs:Int
    var matrix: [Int]


    init(zs: Int, ys:Int, xs:Int) {
        self.zs = zs
        self.ys = ys
        self.xs = xs
        matrix = Array(count:zs*ys*xs, repeatedValue:0)
    }

    subscript(z:Int, ys:Int, xs:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return matrix[ zs * ys * xs + ys ]
        }
        set {
            matrix[ zs* ys * xs + ys ] = newValue
        }
    }

    func zsCount() -> Int {
        return self.zs
    }

    func colCount() -> Int {
        return self.ys
    }

    func rowCount() -> Int {
        return self.xs
    }
}

var dungeon = Array3D(zs: 5, ys: 5, xs: 5)


dungeon[1,0,0] = 1
dungeon[0,4,0] = 2
dungeon[0,0,4] = 3
dungeon[0,4,4] = 4

print("You created a dungeon with \(dungeon.zsCount()) z value \(dungeon.colCount()) columns and \(dungeon.rowCount()) rows. Here is the dungeon visually:\n\n")


for z in 0..<5 {
for y in 0..<5 {
    for x in 0..<5 {
        print(String(dungeon[z,x,y]))
    }
    print("\n")
}
    print("\n")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in how the index is calculated in the subscript. To convert `(z, y, x)` into a linear coordinate you can use:

```
z * ys * xs + y * xs + x
```

So the subscript should be fixed as follows:

```
subscript(z:Int, y:Int, x:Int) -> Int {
    get {
        return matrix[ z * ys * xs + y * xs + x ]
    }
    set {
        matrix[ z * ys * xs + y * xs + x ] = newValue
    }
}
```

Notice that indexes in the print statement inside the loop are inverted:

```
print(String(dungeon[z,x,y]))
```

It should be `[z, y, x]` instead

With these changes, this is the output I obtain in a playground:

```
00003
00000
00000
00000
20004

10000
00000
00000
00000
00000

00000
00000
00000
00000
00000

00000
00000
00000
00000
00000

00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

**Addendum**
`zs`, `ys` and `xs` represent the size of the 3d matrix: there are `xs` columns, `ys` rows and `zs` planes. The size of each column is `xs`, the size of each plane is `xs * ys`.

For y = 0 and z = 0, the element in the array corresponding to x = 3 is the 4th element, having index 3 (the array is zero based, as well as the 3d coordinates). If y = 1, the element is 3 + the size of a row, which is 3 + 5 = 8. To make it more generic

```
x + xs * y = 3 + 1 * 5 = 8
```

The size of each plane instead is xs * ys, corresponding to 25. So the z coordinate must be multiplied by that size. That leads to the formula I used:

```
z * ys * xs + y * xs + x
```

In case of z = 0, with coordinates (0, 1, 3):

```
0 + 1 * 5 + 3 = 8
```

If z = 1, the coordinates are (1, 1, 3), and the formula results in:

```
1 * 5 * 5 + 1 * 5 + 3 = 33
```

and so forth.

If that sounds complicated, look at the output generated by the code, consisting of 5 blocks of 5 rows, each one containing 5 numbers. If you translate that into a single line (by removing the newlines) you can obtain the array index by counting from zero up to the desired element, from left to right. You can jump to the next row by adding 5 to an index, and to the next plane by adding 25.

Hope that clarifies a little bit.

Comment: @Antonion Thank You! It works! What is the difference between z and zs, y and ys, x and xs? Will you explain to me why is the linear coordinate z * ys * xs + y * xs + x  ? I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. I still need some time to understand it and I do appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. I have a question to seek your advice. Do you know is there any difference between the multidimensional arrays structure between Basic C language and swift? Because, i have a basic C code with 3D arrays to do certain calculations (minus, addition, multiplication and subtraction) to get some results. Right now, I am bringing it over to Xcode using SWIFT language. Is this possible?

Comment: I still unsure right now because it seems like a run time error, and i have not find the problem out yet...

Comment: I haven't used C with swift, so I cannot answer to that question. There's [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11) in the swift reference manual talking about interaction with C code - you can probably find your answers there

Comment: Actually i am asking specifically, if is there any difference like how a 3D Array being stored and used in Basic C code and Swift. For example in Basic C, I can just simply declare Dungeon[5][5][5], but have to use the class above for Swift language.The swift reference manual didn't mention any of it... @Antonio It is okay, do not wish to pressure you over these. You have already helped me a lot!

Comment: You can create multi dimensional arrays in swift - a couple examples [here](https://gist.github.com/jeden/f7f36fd49cf17bb0e6ab). Not as easy as in C though.

Comment: I wish to clarify for the explanation above. Is there an error in typing? Should it be this instead? For y = 0 and z = 0, the element in the array corresponding to x = 3 is the 4th element, having index 4 (the array is zero based, as well as the 3d coordinates). If y = 1, the element is 4 + the size of a row, which is 4 + 5 = 9. To make it more generic